# C++ - passing declared array as argument to struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
    float_t rotations[6] = {1.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
    fla_algo_config_t config_alt = {20.0f,
                                20.0f,
                                {1.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f},
                                mock_error_callback,
                                nullptr};

    fla_algo_config_t config = {20.0f,
                                20.0f,
                                rotations,
                                mock_error_callback,
                                nullptr};
```

config_alt works. However, it is cumbersome to write out the entire array each time I would like to pass it to the struct. I would like to just pass the `rotations` array directly, so it doesn't need to be rewritten.

However, I get the following error:

`error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
                                 nullptr};`

I am guessing it wants me to enclose rotations with braces. However, if I do this, now I am passing an array of arrays, but `fla_algo_config_t` expects an array.

How can I pass the array? I have tried passing *rotations, but this only passes the first value.

Comment: replace `float_t ...[6]` by `std::array<float_t, 6>` (in `fla_algo_config_t` declaration too) and wonder how did your problems go away.

Comment: I can't do this, unfortunately. I don't have control over the fla_algo_config_t declaration.

Comment: You can initialize it like `{rotations[0], rotations[1], rotations[2], ... rotations[5]}`.

Comment: What is the definition of `fla_algo_config_t`?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```cpp
#define ROTATIONS {1.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f}
fla_algo_config_t config_alt = {20.0f,
                                20.0f,
                                ROTATIONS,
                                mock_error_callback,
                                nullptr};
```

If you still need `rotations[]`, you can still do

```cpp
float_t rotations[6] = ROTATIONS;
```

If you want to use an initialization list, you *have to* use curly braces. See e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).
Therefore, you cannot just pass `rotations`, because it's not an initialization list, but an array.

Another option if you don't like the `#define`:

```cpp
void initFlaAlgoConfig(fla_algo_config_t& config, float_t (&rotations)[6]) // FYI: The 6 should not be hard coded ;)
{
  // or use memcpy()
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
  {
    config.thirdMember[i] = rotations[i];
  }
}
```

Then it could work like this:

```cpp
float_t rotations[6] = {1.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
fla_algo_config_t config = {20.0f,
                            20.0f,
                            {0}, // default, will be overwritten in initFlaAlgoConfig()
                            mock_error_callback,
                            nullptr};
initFlaAlgoConfig(config, rotations);
```

However, this will cost you runtime.